# Why do my GCE instances auto-restart every 6 hours?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've got the following setup:

1. Instance template for n1-standard-1 instances, HTTP(S) accessible, on SSD disks
2. Instance group with named ports for 80/443, autoscaling turned on with min/max=2/10 instances, target CPU=60%, cool-down=60s, and initial delay=600s
3. Group health check on port 80 every 10s with a threshold of 3 attempts
4. GCE HTTP(S) load balancer with above group as HTTP backend, max CPU=80%, health check identical to the one defined above for the group

Everything else is default. What I'm seeing from my graphs is that my 2 instances are regularly re-starting for no apparent reason. The instances both re-start every 6 hours, but staggered an hour apart so they're at least never down at the same time. The instance template is made from the disk of an instance that ran reliably (i.e. without regular, inexplicable re-starts) for months outside of an auto-scaling group. I've never seen one of my instances listed as unhealthy in the LB dashboard, but if I had to guess, I'd guess that my health checks are misconfigured somehow. Thanks.

Running "gcloud compute operations list" yields events of type "compute.instances.repair.recreateInstance" the correspond exactly to the periodic restarts. I have no idea why this is happening and haven't found any clues searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instances are restarted because they are probably unhealthy. Please check whether [BackendSevrice.GetHealth(group)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/get-health) returns HEALTHY for all of the instances. If not, this might be case of your server as well as some misconfiguration in firewalls for range 130.211.0.0/22 (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks)

Comment: Thanks for the debugging steps. The issue went away on its own, but if it recurs I will try this. There were massive, coordinated DDoS attacks on that day which might have resulted in unusual network latency.